# I cant relocate or reverse string python

Tags: python, string, date, format, reverse

So my question is, how to manipulate date positions to get the desired output...

```py
date = "12-01-2011"
#       MM-DD-YYYY
# I want to output: YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: Are you sure that `23` is `MM`?

Comment: "im trying", then show that code you've written

Comment: Yes, im distracted thinking how i can do that...

Comment: I doit, so now, could you all helpme please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `datetime` function

```
from datetime import datetime
date = "12-01-2011"
datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(date,'%d-%m-%Y')
newformat = datetime.strftime(datetimeobject,'%Y-%m-%d')
print(newformat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the string is a fixed format, you can use string slicing and a f-string.

```
date = "12-01-2011"
date_year = date[6:]
date_month = date[0:2]
date_day = date[3:5]

#Then print with f string

print(f"{date_year}-{date_month}-{date_day}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it.

```
date = "12-01-2011"

date_list = date.split('-')
date_list[0], date_list[1], date_list[2] = date_list[2], date_list[0], date_list[1]

date = "-".join(date_list)

print(date)
```